# how to insert in mysql for this condition?

Tags: mysql

I need help. I'm learning sql and it's my first time doing this.
Table:

1. book with attribute: book id and book title.
2. review with attribute: review id and comment.

Associative table: book_id(FK book id) and review_id (FK review id)

Book and review is joined by the associative table.. I want to insert in table review in column comment using book title. How can I do this?

Comment: I can't see association table about book and review
Why you not adding field id book in review table?

Comment: didn't really thought about that... I will delete the association table and just use the book id in review table... thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the data model should be

1. book with attribute: book id and book title.
2. review with attribute: review id, book id and comment. Where book id is Foreign key from books table.
   And no need of Associative table

Currently in your scenario,
Let's say book id is 1 for the book title

1. first insert the records into review with attribute table
2. Then insert the record in Associative table with book id and review id

```
INSERT INTO  review with attribute(2,'test Review');
INSERT INTO Associative table(book id, review id) Values (1,2);
```

Comment: Thank you.... I think i should fix my model first..